# How do i read multiple pandas dataframe with for loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop

I have multiple different pandas dataframe, I want to read all of them. How do I do it with for loop, since the variable names is different.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'index':1,'text':['this is text in df1','this is text in df1']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'index':1,'text':['this is text in df2','this is text in df2']})
df3=pd.DataFrame({'index':1,'text':['this is text in df3','this is text in df3']})
```

i tried this

```
df_names=[df1,df2,df3]
for item in df_names['text']:
    print(item)
```

Expected output is a different list with the text of each df
example

```
lst1=['this is text in df1','this is text in df1']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code :

```
ls1=[]
ls2=[]
ls3 =[]
names = [df1,df2,df3]
ls_name = [ls1,ls2,ls3]
for i,j in zip(names,ls_name):
    j.append(i['text'].to_list())
for x in ls_name:
    print(x)


[['this is text in df1', 'this is text in df1']]
[['this is text in df2', 'this is text in df2']]
[['this is text in df3', 'this is text in df3']]
```

Hope it helps